# select the maximum

Tags: database, oracle10g

I have a table:

```
sou_id  sou-name  rool_upid  roll_upname
1        AA          null       null
2        BB          null       null
3        CC          null       null
1        DD          null       null
2        EE          null       null
5        CC          null       null
```

I need to first use an update statement to get --if there is same id  with multiple names I need to get maximum of it in `roll_upid` and `roll_upname`

i.e.
AFTER UPDATE THE ABOVE TABLE SHOULD HAVE VALUES LIKE THIS

```
sou_id  sou-name  rool_upid  roll_upname
1        AA           1          DD
2        BB           2          EE
3        CC           3          CC
1        DD           1          DD
2        EE           2          EE
5        CC           5          CC
```

Now AGAIN check  and update gor ---- if the `roll_upname` is same and `roll_upid` is multiple take maximum.

I need another Update statement for this.

Thus final table after the 2nd update should be like this:

```
sou_id  sou-name  rool_upid  roll_upname
1        AA           1          DD
2        BB           2          EE
3        CC           5          CC
1        DD           1          DD
2        EE           2          EE
5        CC           5          CC
```

please help as soon as psossible i need it
thanx in advance

Comment: Could you please add some formatting to your table examples, as well as tag this with the specific technologies you are using (SQL Server 2005, MySql, etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for reformatting the tables, but I must admit I'm still unable to comprehend the question, let alone answer it.  If I knew what "sou", "rool", "roll", and "upname" meant... well, no promises...

Comment: sou ,rool ,roll are the  column name
 plz dont care abt that

Comment: Now I don't want to help you anymore.

Comment: why? i think no one is able to solve this question

Comment: @prabin: People on this site may help you for *free*.  When someone is doing you a favor, it's rude and ungracious to be impatient.  Even worse is using all caps, which is interpreted as shouting.  If you have a need for immediate service, go hire someone at RentACoder or similar place.

Comment: Furthermore, you have shown that you don't care enough about your own question to format it clearly, or describe what you have tried yourself, or even give details about what brand of database you're using.  So why should anyone else care about your problem any more than you do?

Comment: Question needs to be written more clearly.

Comment: actually i am using 0racle 10 g and  i have tried it but
this is my first update stetment which worked: update X  set (X.rool_upid, X.roll_upname)=(select sou_id,sou_name  from t where X.sou_id=t.sou_id );


but
update X  set X.rool_upid=(select max(sou_id) from t where x.roll_upname=t.sou_name);
this second update doesnt work  as it select maximum id if there was 6 it wpold have slected 6 instead of 5 please help in this second update stement

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TABLE1
>     (SOU_ID int, SOU_NAME varchar2(2), ROOL_UPID varchar2(4), ROLL_UPNAME varchar2(4));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>     INTO Table1 (SOU_ID, SOU_NAME, ROOL_UPID, ROLL_UPNAME)
>          VALUES (1, 'AA', NULL, NULL)
>     INTO Table1 (SOU_ID, SOU_NAME, ROOL_UPID, ROLL_UPNAME)
>          VALUES (2, 'BB', NULL, NULL)
>     INTO Table1 (SOU_ID, SOU_NAME, ROOL_UPID, ROLL_UPNAME)
>          VALUES (3, 'CC', NULL, NULL)
>     INTO Table1 (SOU_ID, SOU_NAME, ROOL_UPID, ROLL_UPNAME)
>          VALUES (1, 'DD', NULL, NULL)
>     INTO Table1 (SOU_ID, SOU_NAME, ROOL_UPID, ROLL_UPNAME)
>          VALUES (2, 'EE', NULL, NULL)
>     INTO Table1 (SOU_ID, SOU_NAME, ROOL_UPID, ROLL_UPNAME)
>          VALUES (5, 'CC', NULL, NULL)
> SELECT * FROM dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> update table1 t
> set t.roll_upname = (select max(table1.sou_name) from table1 where table1.sou_id = t.sou_id)
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> update table1 t
> set t.rool_upid = (select max(table1.sou_id) from table1 where table1.roll_upname = t.roll_upname)
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1
> ```
>
> ```
> SOU_ID | SOU_NAME | ROOL_UPID | ROLL_UPNAME
> -----: | :------- | :-------- | :----------
>      1 | AA       | 1         | DD         
>      2 | BB       | 2         | EE         
>      3 | CC       | 5         | CC         
>      1 | DD       | 1         | DD         
>      2 | EE       | 2         | EE         
>      5 | CC       | 5         | CC
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1eba071a0568ca47dde9dac9be7b0bbf)*